# How do I create default folders for new users?

Tags: users, skel

What I want to do is this : When I create a new user in Ubuntu, I want him to have a copy of a folder, let's call him "abc", in his own home directory. Is there any way to automate this or do I have to copy the folder by myself each time?

Can I for example use /etc/skel for this job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Anything sitting in `/etc/skel` will be copied out to **new** user accounts. Old accounts aren't affected by changes to it.